# Technology behind these drawing apps

Tags: javascript, css, html, draw

Can anyone please tell me what could be the technology behind http://realtimeboard.com/ and http://draw.io/? I am interested in learning that and develop such a software for as my project?

Comment: There are many technologies involved, commonly summed up as *HTML5*. What specifically are you asking for? Notice there are "about" links in both pages, and you can simply inspect the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they use Canvas 2d (HTML5 API).
There are a ton of tutorials about drawing oncanvas:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial
- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Here are some libraries about canvas drawing:

- http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/10-cool-javascript-drawing-canvas-libraries/
- http://fabricjs.com/ - Fabric.js is a powerful and simple Javascript
  HTML5 canvas library
- http://kineticjs.com/ - Enterprise class interactive web graphics

Don't rush when you pick your drawing library.

---

**UPDATE**:

- realtimeboard.com seems to be based on Shockwave Flash only, see this piece of code:
  `<div id="realtimeboardApp"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="rtbLoader"></object></div>`. I wont discuss this much further.
- draw.io source code:
  `<div class="geDiagramContainer"><svg shape-rendering="optimizeSpeed" >[...]</svg></div>`
  `<div class="geOutlineContainer"><svg style="[....] min-width: 3251px; min-height: 2768px;">...</svg></div>` Seems to be based on SVG only, however, it still contains some SWF flash object, perhaps as a fallback mechanisms for older browsers and Internet Explorer.

On draw.io site I could identify the following libraries:

- http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html (just as Yuryi says), a proprietary JavaScript drawing library, a license costs between 3800€ - 25000€;
- http://www.mathjax.org/, open source library for displaying math formulae.

I don't know much about Flash, except that it's obsolete, good for working with older browsers and that Adobe has discontinued its development in favor of HTML.

Updated:
MxGraph is open source now. It is now an option

**Conclusion**:
Although SVG seems a good technological solution, however mxGraph would not be an option for me, considering the costs and licensing restrictions on my code.
If you want a drawing library look at my earlier recommendations, or look for a SVG drawing library at http://www.farinspace.com/top-svg-javascript-libraries-worth-looking-at/.

Comment: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph and https://github.com/jgraph/draw.io

Answer (score 2):

Unfamiliar with realtimeboard, but draw.io is made via workflow library MXGRAPH: http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html you can request a trial version, there's documentation, forums, sample projects etc. We're using it in our applications and it's pretty awesome.